# Properly retrieve and display data from Mongoose / MongoDB .find method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a command line app in Node.js that involves retrieving results from a database (DB) using Mongoose. One important function I created just is not working no matter how hard I try and how many tutorials I go through.

The main purpose of the function is to look and see if the database (a simple word bank) has an entry containing given phrase / word.

Here is the full code setup for the particular function:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    mongoSettings = {
        useNewUrlParser: true,
        useUnifiedTopology: true
    },
    wordSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
        { item: String }
    );

/**
 * Looks for a given word or phrase in database.
 * Will eventually return a boolean.
 * 
 * @param {string} word2LookUp Word or phrase to search for
 * @param {string} lang Which language list to search in [english (default), spanish, or french]
 */

const inWordBank = (word2LookUp,lang="english") => {
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/word-bank', mongoSettings);
    mongoose.connection
      .once("open",()=>{
        console.log(`// ----- Searching for: "${word2LookUp}"...`);

        const Word = mongoose.model('Word', wordSchema,lang);
        Word.find({item: word2LookUp}, function (err, words) {

            console.log(words); // <---------[ WHERE I'M HAVING TROUBLE ]

        });

        mongoose.connection.close();
      })
      .on("error", error => {
        console.log(">>> Error: ",error)
        mongoose.connection.close();
      });
}

module.exports = {
    inWordBank: inWordBank
}
```

This is how I am trying to execute the function on my `app.js` file:

```
const wordBank = require("./wordBank");

wordBank.alreadyRegistered("fem");
```

All I get in the console is:

```
// ----- Searching for: "fem"...
undefined
undefined
undefined
```

Some additional tidbits:

- There's 3 documents in the particular DB in question that contain "fem" in their "item" section. That's probably why there is `undefined` 3 times for some odd reason.
- The DB works fine when I write to it so I know it's not a connection issue
- There are no other errors generated.
- In my `package.json` file, my dependencies look like this:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "mocha": "^6.2.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "mongoose": "^5.7.10"
  }
```

Is there an important piece of the puzzle I'm simply missing? Or do I have to rewrite this from square 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right now you are searching for the exact value of `word2Lookup`. To search for documents who's `item` contains a string, you have to use regex.

So for `wordBank.alreadyRegistered("fem");` try using `wordBank.alreadyRegistered(/fem/g);`.

Or, at the top of `inWordBank()` you can take the passed string and make a regex out of it like so: `word2Lookup = new RegExp(word2Lookup, 'g');`. Just put that at the top of your `inWordBank()` function.

Edit: There is another issue. Since the value is returning `undefined`, there is actually an error being thrown by MongoDB. Do `console.log(err);` inside the `find` callback and that will tell you the error.

Comment: @DeeGonzalez You're welcome. Also if you want to do a case-insesitive search you can change the `g` to `gi`. The `g` tells it to search throughout the entire string (rather than just starting from the beginning), and `i` will tell it to ignore capital vs lowercase letters.

Answer (score 1):

As [@chirspytoes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3330979/chrispytoes) says it is important to verify if there is no error, you can do it as follows:

```
Word.find({item: word2LookUp}, function (err, words) {

             if(err) { 
                  console.error(err);
                  return; 
                }
            console.log(words);

});
```

The second thing to consider is that the results obtained with the `find()` method come as an array.

Example:

```
[
    {
        "item": "fem..."
    },
    {
        "item": "...fem"
    },
    {
        "item": "fem"
    },
]
```